# Why does starting a line with a comma and space in Jupyter generate a tuple of strings?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I noticed today that in Jupyter notebook, writing `, = 4` produces the surprising output `('=', '4')`. (I was trying to see if comma could be used as a variable. Don't judge me.)

After a few more tests, generally it seems that in Jupyter star a line with `", "` will format whatever is left on the line into a whitespace-separated tuple of strings:

```
, def my_function():
```

produces

```
('def', 'my_function():')
```

and

```
, one_space: two_space:  five_space:     no_space:
```

produces

```
('one_space:', 'two_space:', 'five_space:', 'no_space:')
```

In Python cli this all just gives syntax errors, so this is apparently some kind of Jupyter magic command, but I haven't been able to figure out where this would be documented. Any help and references would be appreciated.

Comment: Here is an explanation: https://www.reddit.com/r/JupyterNotebooks/comments/bs0cnv/comma_at_the_beginning_of_line_outputs_tuple_of/